How to stop saga after specified amount of action calls?
I have a case that I have to call n sagas:
function* mainSaga() {
   yield all(
     someArrayOfIds.map((id) => call(pollSaga, id))
   )
}

pollSaga:
function* pollSaga(id) {
  yield race([
     call(workSaga, id)
     take('STOP_ACTION')
  ])
}

workSaga:
function* workSaga(id) {
  while (true) {
    yield call(...);
    yield delay(...)
  }
}

The thing I'm super struggling here, is how to know when all the pollSagas have finished. As you can see in the pollSaga I can just dispatch the STOP_ACTION but this is useless since it will stop ALL of the sagas (I don't want to stop all the sagas at once).
Difficult for me to properly explain the goal here, but if you are experienced with sagas you will know what I mean. I just want to be able to differentiate between pollSaga calls and to be able to stop each of them separately and somehow "listen" when ALL of them have finished.
Maybe there is a way if I dispatch STOP_ACTION only that specified pollSaga will be cancelled, not all of them?

If you want to be able to stop each worker separately, then you will need to include the id of the worker you want to stop in the STOP_ACTION action, and then modify the take effect in race, to check for that specific id:
function* pollSaga(id) {
  yield race([
    call(workSaga, id),
    take((a) => a.type === 'STOP_ACTION' && a.id === id),
  ])
}
// ...
yield put({type: 'STOP_ACTION', id: 'foo'})

Regarding your second question - how to know when all of the workers finished - the easiest way to do that is just to run some code after the all effect in your mainSaga:
function* mainSaga() {
   yield all(
     someArrayOfIds.map((id) => call(pollSaga, id))
   )
   console.log('This happens once everything is cancelled')
}

This works, because you are using call effect here, which is blocking and so the mainSaga is blocked there until all the call effects in your all combinator are finished.
